# Was Paul the only Mentat in the Atreides bloodline?

Tags: dune

At the age of fifteen, Paul Atreides found that he had Mentat abilities - abilities which were enhanced by his mother's Bene Gesserit training and later proved pivotal in his role as Muad'Dib. His father, Duke Leto I, was surprised to learn this and was the one to tell Paul of his potential:

> "Your mother wanted me to be the one to tell you, son. You see, you
>   may have Mentat capabilities."
>
> Paul stared at his father, unable to speak for a moment, then: "A Mentat? Me? But I . . . "
>
> "Hawat agrees, son. It's true."

Paul's children, Leto II and Ghanima, were the first descendants of the Atreides bloodline to have both male & female ancestral memories. Leto II, of course, would be the one to

> finish what his father started, becoming the God Emperor of Dune and leading humanity along the Golden Path.

I am unclear, however, on whether Paul's children also had mentat abilities, or if they merely inherited his prescience and memories.

**Was Paul Atreides the only one in his bloodline with mentat abilities, or did his children/descendants also have this potential?**

Comment: Paul's son (Leto II, the God Emperor) is a Mentat, a Bene Gesserit, a Kwisatz Haderach and a Truthsayer. He basically has the full set, so to speak.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Miles Teg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miles_Teg#cite_note-Heretics-3) was definitely an Atreides and definitely a Mentat.

> Lady Janet then began to point out the identifiable incongruities that betrayed a Face Dancer to trained eyes and ears. They were subtle signs but Miles picked up on them immediately. His mother told him then that she thought he might become a Mentat … perhaps even more.
>   Shortly before his thirteenth birthday, Miles Teg was sent away to advanced schooling at the Bene Gesserit stronghold on Lampadas, where his mother’s assessment of him was confirmed. Word went back to her:
>   ***“You have given us the Warrior Mentat we had hoped for.”***
>
> <sub><sup>[Heretics of Dune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heretics_of_Dune)</sup></sub>

---

Paul's oldest surviving child, [Leto Atreides II, the God Emperor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leto_II_Atreides) also had the *abilities* of a Mentat without necessarily being one himself. He could call upon the knowledge and capabilities of every person in his bloodline, almost certainly including truthsayers, mentats and countless Bene Gesserit